# Can I undo changes that were made in other git branch?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging

I'm working on a git branch called `x`. Some time ago I had to merge into that branch changes from the branch `y`. Now, since I've finished my work, I would like to publish my changes from branch `x`, so make a Merge Request. But the features that has been made in branch `y` are not yet ready to production, but they will be included in my branch (but I don't need them anymore) - is there an easy solution to "unmerge" changes that has been made when I've merged branch `y` into my branch? (so they won't be included in MR)

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the commits that were merged from branch `y`. For example, using [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

```
pick bba85d4 aaaa
d 7355f82 bbbb
d 03cac01 cccc
pick 6f43992 dddd
pick 37eabec eeee
```

The "d" indicates that you want to remove these two commits. Now save the file, and push the changes.

If you don't want to rewrite history, you can create a new branch, and [`cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the commits you want to include, as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new branch that only includes the changes you wish and then create a new pull request from this:

Let's say you wish to create a new branch from `y` that is reverted back to a commit `1234` and then merge this to `x`:

```
git checkout -b new_branch upstream/master
git cherry-pick 1234
git push -u origin new_branch
```

Then create your pull request from your `new_branch` to `x` etc.

(I might misunderstand the order x -> y or y -> x, but it doesn't really matter. The idea is to create a new branch and cherry-pick up to the changes you wish)